# Send REST request to get data obtained by Postman

Tags: rest, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

I'm in the process of getting some data from Salesforce in order to store them in GCP. It seems that there doesn't exit any tool that directly connects both sides, so the way I'm doing it is by using Postman to send a REST request to Salesforce and therefore getting the data. Now, my question is how I should proceed in order to store those data into Cloud Storage or BigQuery as I can't find the way to create a channel between GCP and Postman (if that is the right thing to do). Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is this a one time thing that you would never do again, or are you looking for a repeatable process, because it might make sense to just write some java or python code that acts as middleware to both where you pull data from the rest api/bulk and write it to GCP instead of manually trying to do it by hand

Comment: Thank you @Gareth Jordan. Now, I'm just trying to do it once as part of a testing process, but in the future it will be a repeatable process for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be best to at least code a prototype a for doing this or a python script.  But you could probably use [cUrl](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_curl.htm) to hit the salesforce api and push the response to a local file and use the cloud tools CLI ([see example from docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/quickstart-gsutil)) to then send it to Cloud Storage. bearing in mind the results from the api call to SF would be in the raw json format.  You can probably combine the different commands into a single bash script to make running end to end repeatable once you have the individual commands working correctly

```
curl https://***instance_name***.salesforce.com/services/data/v42.0/ -H "Authorization: Bearer access_token_from_auth_call" > response.txt

gsutil cp ./response.txt gs://your-gs-bucket
```

Comment: Thank you again @Gareth Jordan. Following your suggestion, I've taken the cUrl code given by Postman, which surprisingly works just fine inside Postman (when importing it), but fails when running through the command line (apparently, it does nothing and no error messages are prompted). So, I'm unable to test the whole process, but I get your point. At the end, it seems that an intermediate file is needed in order to load te data from Salesforce to GCP (unless using Analytics 360).

Comment: Be sure to either surround the access token in quotes or escape the ! With a \!

Comment: Yes, I checked that, but it did not work neither. Anyway, the process is as you mention above. Thanks again!